# Avoiding line breaks with Saxon XSLT processor

Tags: saxon

Am testing xsl:output in current saxon9he.jar and trying to use the following invocation:

```
    <xsl:output encoding="UTF-8" media-type="text/plain"
        indent="yes" method="text" saxon:line-length="1000"/>
```

which results in 
        "Exception in thread "main" net.sf.saxon.trans.LicenseException: 
        Requested feature (custom serialization {http://saxon.sf.net/}line-length) requires Saxon-PE"

Meanwhile in another stylesheet, the following seems to work:

```
    <xsl:result-document href="{$sourceFilePath}" method="html" omit-xml-declaration="yes"
         encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" saxon:line-length="120">
```

Upgrading to paid PE version is not an option, since this work is part of an open-source standards-development project which must be repeatable.  Also didn't want to refactor stylesheets (and invocations) from xsl:output to xsl:result-document.

Am hoping that consistent implementation support might be possible for both xsl elements.

References for saxon:line-length are
        http://www.saxonica.com/documentation9.5/extensions/output-extras/line-length.html
and
        http://www.saxonica.com/documentation/index.html#!changes/serialization/9.2-9.3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The general rule is that all Saxon extensions require Saxon-PE. I think the correct action for Saxon-HE for both of these should be to output a warning and ignore the request: I'll check to see if that's what's happening.

We're happy to provide an XSLT processor with high conformance to the open source community; the fact that we are able to do that is thanks to the people who pay for the commercial versions. I'm sorry if this sometimes means that open source users can't always have all the functionality they would like, but without this business model, open source users would have nothing.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  If the tools indeed do nothing special that forces use of an extension, that will be great.  What caused the difficulty in the first place was saxon9he.jar (it seems overzealously) inserting a line break around column 80, literally breaking long lines of source-code output.  Letting the stylesheet itself control all text (including line breaks) seems like a good default.

Comment: The spec says for `method=html, indent=yes`, that the processor should try and insert whitespace in a way that maximizes readability of the raw HTML without changing the way it is rendered by the browser, and Saxon is zealously trying to achieve that aim.